# Explode a POST variable after a pattern REGEX

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm terrible at regex, hard to understand for me so I need some help.  I have a variable which looks something like this:

```
["data:image/png;base64,Ivksfk...=", "data:image/png;base64,JksdkJkf...=", "data:image/png;base64,okKJjfeiw...="]
```

Those are 3 values which I want to split into an array.  The way I see it, I want to split it at the comma which comes after a quote `", "`.  Can someone please help me with the regex for `preg_split`?

Comment: You do realize that this is a JSON array, right? There is a PHP built-in parser for that.

Comment: if you do want to split them, use `explode`: `explode( ', ', $str )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below code to split the input string according to `", "`

```
<?php
$yourstring = '["data:image/png;base64,Ivksfk...=", "data:image/png;base64,JksdkJkf...=", "data:image/png;base64,okKJjfeiw...="]';
$regex = '~", "~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $yourstring);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ["data:image/png;base64,Ivksfk...=
    [1] => data:image/png;base64,JksdkJkf...=
    [2] => data:image/png;base64,okKJjfeiw...="]
)
```

If you don't want `"[`,`]"` in the output then you could try the below code.

```
<?php
$data = '["data:image/png;base64,Ivksfk...=", "data:image/png;base64,JksdkJkf...=", "data:image/png;base64,okKJjfeiw...="]';
$regex =  '~(?<=\["|", ")[^"]*~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => data:image/png;base64,Ivksfk...=
            [1] => data:image/png;base64,JksdkJkf...=
            [2] => data:image/png;base64,okKJjfeiw...=
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '["data:image/png;base64,Ivksfk...=", "data:image/png;base64,JksdkJkf...=", "data:image/png;base64,okKJjfeiw...="]';

$parts = preg_split('/,\s/', $string);

var_dump($parts);
```

Program output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) ""data:image/png;base64,Ivksfk...=""
  [1]=>
  string(36) ""data:image/png;base64,JksdkJkf...=""
  [2]=>
  string(37) ""data:image/png;base64,okKJjfeiw...=""
}
```

Comment: why not simply `explode(', ', ...)`

Comment: He said regex, so it reminded me of preg_split because preg_split takes a regex

Answer (score 0):

So long as the double-quote symbol cannot occur within the double-quotes that contain the content, this pattern should validate and capture the three values:

```
^\["([^"]+)"\], \["([^"]+)"\], \["([^"]+)"\]$
```

If double-quotes can appear within the content, or the number of values is variable, then this pattern will not work.